# No se muestran las clases dentro del package en Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

Les hago una pequeña consulta ya que estoy jugando un poco con eclipse y me he encontrado con este tema. No se me muestran las clases dentro del package en el IDE. Si me dirijo a la ubicación del proyecto, las clases están allí.

Agradecería cualquier orientación. Les dejo capturas de lo que describo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Dale F5 para refrescar, también puedes dar en la parte superior Project>Clean Project.

Comment: Genial, ha funcionado refrescando. Porque pasa esto? me gustaría llegar a la raíz del problema para solucionarlo en algún momento.

Comment: Si haces cambios "fuera de eclipse", éste no los detecta hasta que refrescas el proyecto. IntelliJ o VS Code sí están contínuamente monitorizando el sistema de ficheros, pero eso añade un coste de memoria, por lo que es cuestión de gustos qué es mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es debido a que estas en "Package Explorer", Ve a `Window` > `ShowView` > `Navigator`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]